# Changing arrow directions in collapsible menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a collapsible menu and I want to change the direction of the arrows as I click to show or hide the content. I'm using Font Awesome icons as my arrows. Here's a pretty basic collapse menu HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h6>
            <a id="menu-one-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menuOne">
                BUDGET <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </h6>
    </div>

    <div id="menuOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            CONTENT HERE.
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h6>
            <a id="menu-two-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#menuTwo">
                CATEGORY <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </h6>
    </div>

    <div id="menuTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            CONTENT HERE TOO.
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically I want to change fa-arrow-right to fa-arrow-down when I want to open the menu, and vice versa.

EDIT:

So I managed to change the arrow directions with the toggleClass, but when I click on one menu, the arrow of the second menu also changes... even if I gave them distinct IDs and separated their jQuery. I edited the HTML code and I'll add my JS below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-one-collapse').click(function () {
        $("i").toggleClass("fa-arrow-down");
    });

    $('#menu-two-collapse').click(function () {
        $("i").toggleClass("fa-arrow-down");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gWz2/

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. jQuery `toggleClass()` will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#budget-collapse').click(function(){
        $child=$(this).children('i');
        $child.toggleClass("fa-arrow-right").toggleClass("fa-arrow-down");
    });
});
```

Note: Don't forget to include jQuery library in `head` section

Comment: the toggleclass worked perfectly, but I added another collapsible menu and that menu's arrow also changes direction when the first one is clicked.

Comment: Change the code `$("i").toggleClass("fa-arrow-down");` to `$(this).children("i").toggleClass("fa-arrow-down");` Explanation: `$('i')` will select all the elements with tagname `i`